# unhandled rejection timeouterror: resourcerequest timed out

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting this error in my node program with sequelize.

```
unhandled rejection timeouterror: resourcerequest timed out
```

Upon searching on internet I realized its to do with the pool settings. I have the following pool setting in sequelize.

```
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
    acquire: 40000
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Same problem here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990489/postgres-on-azure-unhandled-rejection-timeouterror-resourcerequest-timed-out)

Comment: Set ```acquire``` to ```1000000``` and ```max``` to ```30```. Let me know if it works.