# Postgres on AZURE Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, pg

I have a database postgres on azure, whith General Purpose, 2 vCore(s), 100 GB.

at this moment, when i do a simple request to database, database answer me lot of times with message:

```
Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out
at ResourceRequest._fireTimeout (/Project/development/TFS-git/RAILES/railes-backend-api-pt-0317/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:62:17)
at Timeout.bound (/Project/development/****/*****/*********/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:8:15)
at ontimeout (timers.js:458:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:296:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:259:5)
```

i'm using nodejs, "pg": "7.5.0", "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2", "sequelize": "4.41.0",

i also tryed to scale database to 32 cores, but CPU is more than 95% in both cases.

my pool: `pool: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                acquire: 10000,
                idle: 5,
                evict: 8
            },`

in some cases, the connection give-me a timeout with 2 minuts.

any idea?

Comment: Hello, did u find any solution?

Comment: @CoderX Set ```acquire``` to ```1000000``` and ```max``` to ```30```. Let me know if it works.